# Displaying message on a computer over LAN

Tags: vb.net

How can I display a message (Using vb.net) on a computer that is attached through LAN?
Can I use IP Address of that computer: How?

Please give me code sample.

Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the shell command "net send". There's an example on CodeProject.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/CfSimpleSendComp.aspx